# All about (co)algebras for the identity functor

Tags: category-theory

Any fact about these would be of interest. Has anyone seen an interesting structure constructed from a monad and comonad based on a single identity functor?

I am working on a very small example just so that I can do all the calculations.  In particular, suppose I have a category with one object that's a set with two elements. The morphisms are all endo-functions of this set. Now take the identity endo-functor and use it to generate a monad and comonad. Next, find the (co)algebra for these. Are these completely trivial?

Comment: Does anyone want to say definitively that there are no interesting (co)monads based on identity functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unwind the definition. A monad on the identity functor is just a pair of endomorphisms $\eta$ and $\mu$; the defining identities for a monad are automatically defined.

An algebra for this monad is an endomorphism $h$ such that:

- $h \circ h = \mu \circ h$
- $\eta \circ h = 1$

In your problem, the endomorphisms form a group, and so there is a unique algebra $h = \mu$ if $\eta \circ \mu = 1$, and no algebras otherwise.

Comment: Hey, I can't vote your answer up yet as i have no reputation points.  In lieu of that: Thanks!

Comment: @Ben: I think you should still be able to click the check mark, if you want to accept this as the answer.

Comment: I gave it the check.  Thanks again.